# form not defined in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, dom

i'm trying to get the value of the element option:

```
<div id="decorazioni_agg">Decorazioni aggiuntive:<br>
        <select id="decorazioni" name="decorazioni">
            <option class="option" value="smarties">Smarties</option>
            <option class="option" value="scaglie">Scaglette di
                            cioccolato</option>
            <option class="option" value="cheerios">Cheerios</option>
            <option class="option" value="chocopops">Choco 
                            Pops</option>
        </select><br>

        <input class="button" name="aggiungi" type="button" value="Aggiungi 
                    decorazione" onClick="add_decoration(decorazioni.value)">
    </div>
```

And this is the function add_decoration(obj):

```
function add_decoration(tipo)
{
if(tipo == 'smarties')
    add_smarties();
else
    add_something(tipo);
}
```

Now, this is working both with Chrome and IE8 but not with Firefox 3.5; the firefox error console says:

```
decorazioni is not defined
```

How can i do without using a bunch of switch so i can keep my code clean?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="var elem = document.getElementById('decorazioni'); add_decoration(elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value);"
```

However, it would be better to use proper event registration instead of inline events. Here's a jQuery example; to make it work give the button an id:

```
$('#buttonid').on('click', function() {
    add_decoration($('#decorazioni').val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not bind event handlers in HTML.

```
<input class="button" id="aggiungi" name="aggiungi" type="button" value="Aggiungi decorazione" />

document.getElementById('aggiungi').onclick= function () {
    add_decoration(document.getElementById('decorazioni').value);
};
```

Comment: Thank you, there is no way of doing this binding event handlers in HTML and without using jquery?I don't get the sense of that error. I king "have" to use event handlers in HTML.

Comment: the code i posted is native javascript, though it can be done in jquery if you prefer (see ThiefMaster's answer)

Comment: and for the reason why: [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns#HTML.2C_CSS.2C_and_JavaScript)